# tortoise svn checkout access forbidden and not prompting for login

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sspi

I have been using tortoise svn for a long time on this pc but it has suddenly stopped working.

I was performing svn checkout via tortoise and it returns the error:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL: <url>
Access to <path-to-repo> forbidden
```

Additionally:

- In tortoise SVN there is no authentication cached. I looked at
  Settings / saved data. Tortoise should have prompted for login but it
  does not.
- I can execute the exact same svn checkout from another machine and it works fine so it is not a permissions problem. I even copy/pasted
  the exact URL so the URL is exactly the same.
- I am able to checkout other svn server repos fine on the same pc with the same tortoisesvn client. I get a proper prompt from svn for login as required.
- I can use a browser on the same pc to open the svn url fine. The browser prompts for a login as required.
- I have already tried uninstalling/re-installing tortoisesvn and that has not fixed the problem.
- svn server version: 1.5.3
- httpd version: 2.2.10 running SSPIAuth module
- tortoisesvn client version: 1.9.3
- client OS: windows 2007 64-bit

Comment: Are you matching the case of the URL exactly? Windows is case-insensitive, SVN's path-based authorization is case-sensitive, and Apache is *mostly* case-sensitive but when it comes to host filesystem paths, it does whatever the host OS/filesystem does.

Comment: Sorry. No joy. Tried a shorter path which I know to be exactly matched. It does not work. The error is the same--access denied. The longer path does work both in the browser and from a redhat client. I am also defined as admin in AuthzSVNAccessFile

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue for me was I did not have an open connection to the target repository. My ethernet cable had been disconnected and my machine was using WiFi instead of our company LAN. The forbidden error was not about credentials, but the connection.

Comment: That's a rather misleading error message if that was the underlying cause.